# As low as on configurable products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price, tierprice

I have several configurable products and a few of them have a higher price than some.

For example, I have a shirt with `3 sizes S, M, L` the `L`is `$3` extra dollars than the other two. I have the simple products created, but when it displays in my store, it says the products are `" as low as (insert price)."`

I don't have tier pricing set up for these products because I've double checked that. How do I remove them as low as if it's not due to tier `pricing`?

Comment: Do you have multiple store? If yes then check at different store views.